# how to insert a fixed number of figures per row/column?

Tags: floats, captions

I have a simple question but I am not sure on how to proceed.
I would like to put 10 figures on the same page: a grid of 5 rows and 2 columns.

What should I type in order to have the figure inserted like this and with equal alignement/size ? Eventually with custom captions... ;)

Comment: Did you take a look at the [`subfig` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are several possibilities here.

### Case A: ten subfigures

Three options: the first one, using the [`subfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) package; the second one, using the [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package; the third one, using the [`floatrow`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) package.

#### Using subfig:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=raggedright}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[first subfigure]{\label{sfig:a}\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}\hfill
\subfloat[second subfigure]{\label{sfig:b}\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}\hfill
\subfloat[third subfigure]{\label{sfig:c}\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}\hfill
\subfloat[fourth subfigure]{\label{sfig:d}\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}\hfill
\subfloat[fifth subfigure]{\label{sfig:e}\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}\\
\subfloat[sixth subfigure]{\label{sfig:f}\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-b}}\hfill
\subfloat[seventh subfigure]{\label{sfig:g}\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-b}}\hfill
\subfloat[eighth subfigure]{\label{sfig:h}\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-b}}\hfill
\subfloat[ninth subfigure]{\label{sfig:i}\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-b}}\hfill
\subfloat[tenth subfigure]{\label{sfig:j}\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-b}}\\
\caption{A figure with ten subfigures}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Using subcaption:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=raggedright}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{first subfigure\label{sfig:a}}{\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{second subfigure\label{sfig:b}}{\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{third subfigure\label{sfig:c}}{\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{fourth subfigure\label{sfig:d}}{\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{fifth subfigure\label{sfig:e}}{\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}\\
\subcaptionbox{sixth subfigure\label{sfig:f}}{\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-b}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{seventh subfigure\label{sfig:g}}{\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-b}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{eighth subfigure\label{sfig:h}}{\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-b}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{ninth subfigure\label{sfig:i}}{\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-b}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{tenth subfigure\label{sfig:j}}{\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-b}}\\
\caption{A figure with ten subfigures}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Using floatrow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\renewcommand\subfloatrowsep{\hskip7pt} 

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright}
\ffigbox[\textwidth]{%
\begin{subfloatrow}[5]
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{first subfigure}\label{sfig:a}}
  {\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{second subfigure}\label{sfig:b}}
  {\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{third subfigure}\label{sfig:c}}
  {\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{fourth subfigure}\label{sfig:d}}
  {\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{fifth subfigure}\label{sfig:e}}
  {\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}
\end{subfloatrow}
\begin{subfloatrow}[5]
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{sixth subfigure}\label{sfig:f}}
  {\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{seventh subfigure}\label{sfig:g}}
  {\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{eighth subfigure}\label{sfig:h}}
  {\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{ninth subfigure}\label{sfig:i}}
  {\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{tenth subfigure}\label{sfig:j}}
  {\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}
\end{subfloatrow}
}{\caption{A figure with ten subfigures}\label{fig:test}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Case B: ten independent figures

If we are talking about an array of ten independent figures, ten `minipage`s can be used.

If the whole construct should be allowed to float, the `minipage`s can go inside a figure environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright}
\centering
\begin{minipage}[t]{.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{first figure}
\label{fig:a}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{second figure}
\label{fig:b}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{third figure}
\label{fig:c}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{fourth figure}
\label{fig:d}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{fifth figure}
\label{fig:e}
\end{minipage}\\
\begin{minipage}[t]{.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{sixth figure}
\label{fig:f}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{seventh figure}
\label{fig:g}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{eighth figure}
\label{fig:h}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{ninth figure}
\label{fig:i}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{tenth figure}
\label{fig:j}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the whole construct shouldn't be allowed to float, the ten `minipage`s can go inside a `minipage` environment (or a `center` environment); in this situation, captions can be provided using `\captionof` (from the `caption` or `capt-of` packages):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright}
\centering
\begin{minipage}[t]{.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{first figure}
\label{fig:a}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{second figure}
\label{fig:b}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{third figure}
\label{fig:c}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{fourth figure}
\label{fig:d}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{fifth figure}
\label{fig:e}
\end{minipage}\\
\begin{minipage}[t]{.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{sixth figure}
\label{fig:f}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{seventh figure}
\label{fig:g}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{eighth figure}
\label{fig:h}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{ninth figure}
\label{fig:i}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{tenth figure}
\label{fig:j}
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: what to say? many thanks for this wonderful answer!

Comment: @Noobie You're welcome! I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need (e.g., hyperref) links to each individual subfigure, then this might work, though it is quite squeezed.  I am also assuming that your figures are a uniform size, since you speak of placing them in a regular array.  Correct me if I'm wrong.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\def\myfig{\rule{.8in}{1in}}
\newcommand\mycap[2]{\parbox[t]{.8in}{\raggedright(#1) #2}}

\begin{figure}
\small\centering
\Shortstack{%
  {\protect\myfig} {\protect\mycap{a}{Caption for subfig a}} {} 
  {\protect\myfig} {\protect\mycap{f}{Caption for subfig f}}
}
\Shortstack{%
  {\protect\myfig} {\protect\mycap{b}{Caption for subfig b}} {} 
  {\protect\myfig} {\protect\mycap{g}{Caption for subfig g}}
}
\Shortstack{%
  {\protect\myfig} {\protect\mycap{c}{Caption for subfig c}} {} 
  {\protect\myfig} {\protect\mycap{h}{Caption for subfig h}}
}
\Shortstack{%
  {\protect\myfig} {\protect\mycap{d}{Caption for subfig d}} {} 
  {\protect\myfig} {\protect\mycap{i}{Caption for subfig i}}
}
\Shortstack{%
  {\protect\myfig} {\protect\mycap{e}{Caption for subfig e}} {} 
  {\protect\myfig} {\protect\mycap{j}{Caption for subfig j}}
}
\caption{Overall Figure Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]