# How to place a caption in the bottom right corner of a grid of images?

Tags: floats, captions, positioning

I have a grid of images as shown below.
[image: Grid of images of 3 rows of 4 columns. Last row has 2 images in columns 1 and 2. The space in columns 3 and 4 is where the main caption goes.]

This is achieved using the code below (taken from: [how to insert a fixed number of figures per row/col])[2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122486/how-to-insert-a-fixed-number-of-figures-per-row-column)

```
\begin{figure}
\captionsetup{justification=centering,textfont=small}
\centering
\subcaptionbox*{A subcaption that is wider than the image above it.}[28mm]{\includegraphics[width=22mm, height=32mm]{pic1}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox*{Another subcaption.}[28mm]{\includegraphics[width=22mm, height=32mm]{pic2}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox*{Another subcaption.}[28mm]{\includegraphics[width=22mm, height=32mm]{pic3}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox*{Another subcaption.}[28mm]{\includegraphics[width=22mm, height=32mm]{pic4}}\\[4mm]
\subcaptionbox*{Another subcaption.}[28mm]{\includegraphics[width=22mm, height=32mm]{pic5}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox*{Another subcaption.}[28mm]{\includegraphics[width=22mm, height=32mm]{pic6}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox*{Another subcaption.}[28mm]{\includegraphics[width=22mm, height=32mm]{pic7}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox*{Another subcaption.}[28mm]{\includegraphics[width=22mm, height=32mm]{pic8}}\\[4mm]
\subcaptionbox*{Another subcaption.}[28mm]{\includegraphics[width=22mm, height=32mm]{pic9}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox*{Another subcaption.}[28mm]{\includegraphics[width=22mm, height=32mm]{pic10}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox*{}[59.3mm]{}
\end{figure}
```

I would like to place a caption in the bottom right (as shown in the attached picture) and be able to control it like a normal caption (i.e. auto numbering, formatting, vertical/horizobtal justification etc). How best to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caption like this?

[image]

Just put caption inside `minipage` or similar `parbox`, which follows last subfigure.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{subcaption}

    \usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

    \begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{A subcaption that is wider than the image above it.}[28mm]{\includegraphics[width=22mm, height=32mm]{example-image}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{Another subcaption.}[28mm]{\includegraphics[width=22mm, height=32mm]{example-image}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{Another subcaption.}[28mm]{\includegraphics[width=22mm, height=32mm]{example-image}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{Another subcaption.}[28mm]{\includegraphics[width=22mm, height=32mm]{example-image}}\\[4mm]
\subcaptionbox{Another subcaption.}[28mm]{\includegraphics[width=22mm, height=32mm]{example-image}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{Another subcaption.}[28mm]{\includegraphics[width=22mm, height=32mm]{example-image}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{Another subcaption.}[28mm]{\includegraphics[width=22mm, height=32mm]{example-image}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{Another subcaption.}[28mm]{\includegraphics[width=22mm, height=32mm]{example-image}}\\[4mm]
\subcaptionbox{Another subcaption.}[28mm]{\includegraphics[width=22mm, height=32mm]{example-image}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{Another subcaption.}[28mm]{\includegraphics[width=22mm, height=32mm]{example-image}}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{59.3mm}% added for caption
    \caption{main caption. text text text text  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Next time please provide MWE begining with `\documentclas{...} and ended with`\end{document} ...

Comment: Sorry, I copied the code from Lyx and forgot to add the necessaries. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that also with the `floatrow`  package and its `\RawCaption` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}


\DeclareFloatVCode{myrowsep}{\vskip 3.5ex}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \floatsetup{justification =centering, rowpostcode=myrowsep, floatwidth = 28mm}
  \captionsetup{justification=centering,textfont=small}
  \ffigbox{
    \begin{subfloatrow}[4]
      \ffigbox{\includegraphics[width=22mm, height=32mm]{pic1}}{\caption{A subcaption}\label{pic1}}%A subcaption that is wider than the image above it
      \ffigbox{\includegraphics[width=22mm, height=32mm]{pic2}}{\caption{A second subcaption}\label{pic2}}
      \ffigbox{\includegraphics[width=22mm, height=32mm]{pic3}}{\caption{A third subcaption}\label{pic3}}
      \ffigbox{\includegraphics[width=22mm, height=32mm]{pic4}}{\caption{A fourth subcaption}\label{pic4}}
    \end{subfloatrow}
    \begin{subfloatrow}[4]
      \ffigbox{\includegraphics[width=22mm, height=32mm]{pic5}}{\caption{A fifth subcaption}\label{pic5}}
      \ffigbox{\includegraphics[width=22mm, height=32mm]{pic6}}{\caption{A sixth subcaption}\label{pic6}}
      \ffigbox[32mm]{\includegraphics[width=22mm, height=32mm]{pic7}}{\caption{A seventh subcaption}\label{pic7}}
      \ffigbox{\includegraphics[width=22mm, height=32mm]{pic8}}{\caption{An eighth subcaption}\label{pic8}}
    \end{subfloatrow}
    \begin{subfloatrow*}[4]
      \ffigbox{\includegraphics[width=22mm, height=32mm]{pic9}}{\subcaption{A ninth subcaption}\label{pic9}}
      \ffigbox{\includegraphics[width=22mm, height=32mm]{pic10}}{\subcaption{A tenth subcaption}\label{pic10}}%
      \ffigbox[\dimexpr56mm + 4em\relax][][t]{}{\captionsetup{justification=RaggedRight}\RawCaption{\parbox[t][32mm]{48mm}{\caption{A global caption.\\ Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. }\label{glo}}}}
    \end{subfloatrow*}
    }{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]